# Time attribute validation in Yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

Is there any way to validate time attribute In MYSQL column contain time datatype. SO i can just validate it through YII.
So is it possible? LIKE
  "`[['from_date', 'to_date'], 'date']`"?

Answer (score 4):

Try this in model rules

```
['attr', 'date', 'format'=>'H:i']
```

For more on this please [refer](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4929)

Answer (score 1):

Use like:

```
[['from_date', 'to_date'], 'date', 'dateFormat' => 'H:i:s']
```

Comment: Thanks; I'll give you the feedback;

Answer (score 1):

You can use [format](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-datevalidator.html#$format-detail) attribute for time validation. It will handle both date and time validation.

```
['attribute_name', 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-M-d H:m:s'],
```

**OR**

```
[['attribute_name1', 'attribute_name2'], 'date', 'format' => 'H:i:s']
```